# Unable to load WSDL. If currently online, please verify the URI and/or format of the WSDL

Tags: apache-flex

We have a Flex Air application that calls web services that sometimes give us this error:

**Unable to load WSDL. If currently online, please verify the URI and/or format of the WSDL**

It's more frequent on OS X, but it does happen on Windows as well. The web services in question are fine, and since it doesn't happen all of the time I don't think it's a configuration problem.

Any idea what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

turns out the timeout on our load balancer was only 30 seconds. We bumped it up to an hour and we haven't seen the problem again. I'd still like a no session option for BlazeDS.